# Returning error with unsigned values?

Tags: c, function, error-handling

I'm making a data structure library. One function I am allowing users to call is:

`unsigned int index(struct myDataStructure, void* value);`

It searches my data structure and returns the `index` location of where that value exists in it.

ex.

`{ 'A', 'D', 'C' }`

```
char val1 = 'A';
unsigned int location = index(s, &val1); // location = 0
char val2 = 'C';
location = index(s, &val2); // location = 2
```

If the element does not exist in the list, then I don't know what to return. Here are the options that I've ruled out so far:

- Using an `Assert` or system exit or exception to end the run-time. I don't think there would be much use in that because the user would have to call `contains` to make sure the element was in the structure before calling `index()`
- Returning UINT_MAX or any constant in the range of 0 <= UINT_MAX. Those could be index values.
- Changing the return type to `long`, so I can return `-1`. I don't want to switch data types.
- Having the user pass in a `**unsigned int` so that I can either point it to `NULL` if does not exist or a real index value. This is not user friendly for people reading my API to understand.

The best solution I had was to do:

```
// Change return type to pointer.
unsigned int* index(struct myDataStructure, void* value)
{
     static int val;

     if (value exists...)
     {
          val = correct index value
          return &val;
     }
     else
     {
          return NULL;
     }
}
```

But I still feel like this solution is very poor.

Comment: You could pass a pointer to a variable that stores an error value: `unsigned int index(struct myDataStructure, void* value, int *status);`.

Comment: You could also consider using the POSIX `ssize_t` type instead of `unsigned`. `ssize_t` is the same width as `size_t`, but is guaranteed to be able to hold a value of `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that returning a pointer to static is bad in many ways. It's not thread safe, and - worse - it invites users to do stuff like

```
int *aIndexLoc = index(data, &a);
int *bIndexLoc = index(data, &b);
if (aIndexLoc && bIndexLoc) 
  printf ("a's loc is %u; b's loc is %u\n", *aIndexLoc, *bIndexLoc);
```

And of course get the wrong answer.

First... If you want your library to be future-proof, then don't return unsigned for an array index. Return `size_t`.

Then... There are several idioms for dealing with error returns. The most common is to return an `int` or enum error code as the function value and the actual return value with a pointer arg. By convention, `0` means "okay" and non-zero values are various error codes. Also, if your data structure is more than a few bytes, don't pass a complete copy of it. Pass a pointer

```
typedef int ERROR;
ERROR index(size_t *result, struct myDataStructure *myStruct, void *valueToFind);
```

and thence something like:

```
size_t loc[1];
struct myDataStructure someData[1];
int aValue[1];

initialize(someData);
get(aValue);

ERROR error = index(loc, someData, aValue);
if (error) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find the value. Error code: %d\n", error);
  return;
}
```

The 1-element array thing is a trick that lets you code the same way whether an object is allocated on the stack or heap. You can treat the name of the array as a pointer. E.g. `someData->fieldName` and `*loc` work just fine.

Comment: One critique though is I really want to avoid polluting the global namespace. Using special error codes would confuse new users to the API.

Comment: @Hatefiend Well,  your example only allows 2 cases: non-null and null.  By extension, ERROR has 2 values: 0 and some non-zero, say 1. The typedef is just a way of giving a name to what's being returned. It's serving as a boolean that says whether there's an error or not.  This isn't polluting a namespace unless you choose to do that.  I can't see users getting very confused on this point. In fact anyone who' done significant C programming will find it very familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities:

- On error return `(unsigned int) -1` using

  ```
  unsigned int index(struct myDataStructure, void* value)
  ```
- On error return `-1` using

  ```
  ssize_t index(struct myDataStructure, void* value)
  ```

  (`ssize_t` is POSIX)
- Pass in the address of an `unsigned int` to point to the result and return `-1` on error and `0` on success, using

  ```
  int index(struct myDataStructure, void* value, unsigned int * result)
  ```

Using

- an assertion I feel is not appropriate here, as it ends your program.
- a static buffer is coding style of the last millennium. It makes your library unusable in a multithreaded context.

Comment: Unfortunately the first option may cause out of bounds with users of my library who aren't careful. The second option uses an external library which I'm not a fan of. It hurts portability. The third one is probably the best option but I can't decide if I should make the `unsigned int` the return value or the parameter. I think maybe the parameter for safety? Make the return type `bool` so as to not do `myArr[index(myArr, "F")]`

Comment: @Hatefiend: "*may cause out of bounds with users of my library who aren't careful*" and "*so as to not do*" In any case you should expect your users to read the documentation and apply proper error checking to each function call which could fail.

Comment: What I meant by that is I want the API calls to be very straightforward to use.

Comment: If `index()` could fail it *may not* be like this `myArr[index(myArr, "F")]`. There is *no way* around it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a pointer to a `bool` that sets as `true` or `false` accordingly.

```
unsigned int index(struct myDataStructure, void *value, bool *ok);
```